# How to subset a dataframe without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, subset

I would like to subset a dataframe without assigning it first to a variable.

Example with assigning:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(5, 15)})
df[(df['A'] > 3) & (df['B'] < 12)]
```

Result:

```
   A   B
4  4   9
5  5  10
6  6  11
```

How to do this without creating `df` first?

Something like...

`pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(5, 15)}).loc[..., ...]`

Or maybe using `.pipe()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [selection by callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(5, 15)})
        .loc[lambda x: (x['A'] > 3) & (x['B'] < 12)])
print (df)
   A   B
4  4   9
5  5  10
6  6  11
```

Another idea with `query`, thank you @sammywemmy:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(5, 15)}).query("A > 3 and B < 12")
#working same
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(5, 15)}).query("A > 3 & B < 12")
```

Comment: just a suggestion : ```pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(5, 15)}).query("A > 3 and B<12")```